# Map a class with List of class in it into another class of similar property using "AutoMapper"

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper

Okay so my issue is that i don't understand how do i map following classes using [Automapper](https://automapper.org/).

```
ClassA
{
    List<ClassA1> classA1 {get; set;}

    ClassA2 ClassA2Object {get; set;}
}

ClassB
{
    List<ClassB1> classB1 {get; set;}

    ClassB2 ClassB2Object {get; set;}
}
```

I have mapped it like

```
CreateMap<ClassA, ClassB>();
```

I have searched and found to use ForPath()
and AfterMap() to set value but failed to map for List of Classes any one know correct way of CreateMap for this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [AutoMapper docs](https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html):

> AutoMapper only requires configuration of element types, not of any array or list type that might be used.

As long as there is a map between the types in the list, eg. `ClassA1` and `ClassB1`, it should work fine.

However, as the property names are different in `ClassA` and `ClassB`, you need to explicitly teach AutoMapper how to map those properties (I slightly changed your code to have public properties):

```
public class ClassA
{
    public List<ClassA1> classA1 { get; set; }

    public ClassA2 ClassA2Object { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public List<ClassB1> classB1 { get; set; }

    public ClassB2 ClassB2Object { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could use it like this example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<ClassA, ClassB>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.classB1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.classA1))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.ClassB2Object, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ClassA2Object));
            cfg.CreateMap<ClassA1, ClassB1>();
            cfg.CreateMap<ClassA2, ClassB2>();
        });

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        var a = new ClassA
        {
            classA1 = new List<ClassA1> { new ClassA1() },
            ClassA2Object = new ClassA2()
        };

        var b = mapper.Map<ClassB>(a);

        Debug.Assert(b.classB1 != null);
        Debug.Assert(b.classB1.Count == a.classA1.Count);
        Debug.Assert(b.ClassB2Object != null);

}
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Your solution helped me a lot!
However i did instantiated the ClassB2Object using AfterMap 
else remained same as you code.Thanks again